# What way is better (use if..else statement or not use)

Tags: c#, .net

Imagine that we have following task:

We must create a method which return the type of input object.

**For example:**

**input:**

*GetTypeObject(23)*

**output:**

*The type of input object is System.Int32*

I think the task is understandable?

Now, I could think of two ways to solve this problem.

**The 1st way:** Create method which contains if ... else statement

**The 2nd way:** Create method which have array with types

*Realisation*

**The 1st way:**

```
private static string GetTypeOfObjectV1(object obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof (int))
                return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof (string))
                return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof (DateTime))
                return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
            if (obj.GetType() == typeof (bool))
                return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
            return null;
        }
```

**The 2nd way:**

```
private static string GetTypeOfObjectV2(object obj)
{
    var listType = new List<Type> { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), typeof(bool) };
    return (from type in listType where obj.GetType() == type select String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", type)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Run methods:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine(GetTypeOfObjectV1("434343"));
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GetTypeOfObjectV1 - ElapsedMilliseconds = {0}",stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GetTypeOfObjectV1 - ElapsedTicks = {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedTicks));

            Stopwatch stopwatch1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine(GetTypeOfObjectV2("434343"));
            stopwatch1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GetTypeOfObjectV2 - ElapsedMilliseconds = {0}", stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GetTypeOfObjectV2 - ElapsedTicks = {0}", stopwatch1.ElapsedTicks));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

*Result:*

[image]

Now, my question is:

**What way is better and why?**

I think the 2nd way better, because in this method we have some optimization. For example, I want to add new type of object. I must add a new type in array. In the 1st method I need to create a new conditional with new type.

But, If I not mistaken, the 1st method work faster than 2nd method and requires less memory.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Why not go with reflection? Each object has a `.GetType()` method.

Comment: @BenjaminDiele excuse me, could you explain me how use reflection in this case?

Comment: @netwer In `GetTypeOfObjectV1`, you have the exact same body in each `if` statement. Why not remove the `if` statements and just use `return string.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());` as the function body? This will make the function work with every input type.

Comment: @netwer Your first way is your answer without lot if conditions :)

Comment: @BenjaminDiele thank for your explain, but I want understand what way is better (if..else statement or no) and my code is only sample.

Comment: @netwer why do you want to choose between if/else logic or a table driven solution? Did you not look at the `switch` statement yet?     As in many things regarding software development, there is no 'golden' solution that works best for every case. If that were possible, only that solution would survive.    Instead, you should ask, wich tool is better for the job at hand.

Comment: @netwer why is the runtime performance of this code important?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I could think of two ways to solve this problem. Then, I tried to understand which solution is best, but I could not understand. Therefore, I decided to ask here. what about performance, the performance in this case one of criterion for choosing the most suitable method.

Comment: @netwer ok, so you're looking for the best solution for this use case, and not a general 'best solution'? I would go with `khlr's answer` then. It doesn't need any of the code constructions you use.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I'm looking the best solution for not this use case, I'm looking for general use case. But this solution is example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to your question, **what is the best general pattern**; There is no `best` pattern for this kind of code. There is a best solution possible for every single given situation. You will need to compare the possible solutions, and weigh the pros and cons against the problem at hand.

Possible solutions:

1. the .GetType() solution
2. if/else if/else logic
3. switch statement
4. table/list lookup
5. business rules logic
6. a fuzzy logic solution
7. ...
8. something else (custom coding)

The `GetType()` solution is the most simple and elegant pattern, but is only possible when the object that you're evaluating has a method that does what you need.

The `if/else` solution is usefull for simple cases, where the list of possible answers is limited (rule of thumb: 3 or less). This solution is hardcoded, and needs to be modified for every case.

The `switch` statement keeps code managable for longer lists op options. It is a nicer way of writing if/else logic. This solution is hardcoded as well. Performance can be better than if/else.

A `table/list lookup` solution is nice, sinc you only need to write the list lookup code once. That code does not change if the list gets longer. The problem that you encounter with a list based approach is that you need to find a way to fill that list, and that method must be maintained. You could read the list from file, or scan objects using reflection, etc... This method is a way to pre-fetch the answers.

A solution that uses `business rules` contains a set of rules, a method to execute these rules against the given data, and a method to evaluate the results to a final answer.

`Fuzzy logic` combines multiple evalutions, and weighs them, leading to a `best` answer. Kind of like what you need to do to choose between these options :-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is very helpful for me. I understood your answer and I got answer on my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

What about simply this?

```
private static string GetTypeOfObjectV3(object obj)
{
    return string.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
}
```

In this case it's better to have no conditions as they're just not necessary. Regardless of the input type, that statement is the same.

Comment: yes, you're right, but I want understand what way is better (if..else statement or no). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second method is better indeed. What happens if those types need to be loaded from somewhere else and you are using the 1st method? Nohing. Nothing as in nothing will work since you have no way to add those values to your hardcoded IFs. That is when your 1st approach will turn into number 2.

Comment: I understood your opinion and I agree with you, thanks!

Comment: How is the second solution not hardcoded? The list creation is hardcoded as well! (even when you load that list from a file, it still requires maintenance of that list).

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ The list in this case is only example.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular task you probably should use meta information about types available in .net for e.g. method GetType(), which available on any instance, will give you a lot information about instance's type.

if you want different logic for different matched types you probably need have a look at Visitor pattern, which makes work with inheritance tree much easier.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

---

Comment: Wow. That's a nice way to make the original overcomplicated solution even more complicated. Perhaps you can throw a factory pattern in there as well?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ Nope, I just want to bring inheritance in the question's author mind. Both solutions (if and map) are not ideal and looks like hardcode, of course map is better but not flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not experienced in C#, it seems like you could solve this problem using the common Object Oriented approach of function overloading. In your class you could define the getObjectType method to take in different types of objects. As long as they return the same type of object it will compile.

So for instance, returning strings:

```
   public class ObjectEvaluator 
   {
        private static string getObjectType (Int obj) {
            return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
        }

        private static string getObjectType (string obj) {
            return String.Format("The type of input object is {0}", obj.GetType());
        }
   }
```

Or you may like to return a Type object. In your main method you would create an instance of the class and call the getObjectType method. Such as:

```
static void main () 
{
    ObjectEvaluator eval = new ObjectEvaluator();
    Console.WriteLine(eval.getObjectType(3));
    Console.WriteLine(eval.getObjectType("something"));
}
```

And so on. The advantage of this is manifold. Maintaining the code is easier: new types of objects can be added or removed in a modular fashion, no more trawling through if statements and such. This approach will enable you to perform different actions based on the type of the object in a more robust fashion that using if ... else or switch statements. Also, performance *might* be improved, since there is no need to step through an if statement.

I hope that this way also answers your question, even though it was not one of the solutions that you proposed yourself.

Comment: How would you add methods to classes like Int32 or String (for wich you can not alter the definition)?  Fortunately, System.Object already provides .GetType(), wich is used in the correct answer by @khlr.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ: as you noted GetType is the way to go. Passing in int32 should not be a problem. By base class I meant a new super class, as in my original answer I thought that an abstract method overridden in subclasses would be the way to go, but changed my approach midway through. I have tidied up that part of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @dashaxiong thank for your answer! Your solution is new for me and I'll look into it in detail, but a little later.